# Actionscript call from javascript throws an exception

Tags: javascript, security, actionscript, cross-domain

I know this subjet isn't new at all but i'm going to be crazy that it doesn't work at all. So I create a "KISS" (Keep It Stupide Simple) sample just to see if it may be something from the original SWF or just a real problem...

HTML is hosted on web site A (actually the Javascript too, but this last one will be moved on web site C) en the swf is hosted at web site B.

Here the swf (from Adobe so it should work...) :

```
import flash.external.*;

Security.allowDomain("*");

var methodName:String = "goHome";
var instance:Object = null;
var method:Function = goToAdobe;
var wasSuccessful:Boolean = ExternalInterface.addCallback(methodName, instance, method);

var txtField:TextField = this.createTextField("txtField", this.getNextHighestDepth(), 0, 0, 200, 50);
txtField.border = true;
txtField.text = wasSuccessful.toString();

function goToAdobe() {
    txtField.text = "http://www.adobe.com";
    getURL("http://www.adobe.com", "_self");
}

stop();
```

and the HTML/Javascript : (HTML generated from Flash itself with FSCommand support (so allowScriptAccess is "always") and the javascript from Adobe too)

```
<!-- saved from url=(0013)about:internet -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>KISS</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var isInternetExplorer = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;

function KISS_DoFSCommand(command, args) {
 var KISSObj = isInternetExplorer ? document.all.KISS : document.KISS;

}
// Hook pour Internet Explorer
if (navigator.appName && navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows") != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows 3.1") == -1) {
 document.write('<script language=\"VBScript\"\>\n');
 document.write('On Error Resume Next\n');
 document.write('Sub KISS_FSCommand(ByVal command, ByVal args)\n');
 document.write(' Call KISS_DoFSCommand(command, args)\n');
 document.write('End Sub\n');
 document.write('</script\>\n');
}
//-->
</script>
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="callExternalInterface()" value="Call ExternalInterface" />
</form>
<script>
function callExternalInterface() {
    thisMovie("KISS").goHome();
}

function thisMovie(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        return window[movieName]
    }
    else {
        return document[movieName]
    }
}
</script>

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" id="KISS" width="550" height="400" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="movie" value="http://www.adopsmanager.com/KISS.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /><embed src="http://www.adopsmanager.com/KISS.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550" height="400" swLiveConnect=true id="KISS" name="KISS" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer_fr" />
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks !

Comment: VBScript? Windows 3.1? How did you get this code? You don't happen to have a time machine, do you? :)

Comment: You should add the exception text as well, that will help people analyze the problem.

Comment: @Robusto some friend of mine say that i can travel in the past so yep I have a time machine :p.

Comment: By the  way the VBScript is generated by Adobe Flash... mine (which isn't the one I pasted) only use javascript ;) There was only to make sure to use trustable/working code.

@Simon Groenewolt I just forgot to talk about this :/ 
The javascript receive a simple "An actionscript exception happen" (no so usefull) since there were no exception from my actionscript code. There were an actionscript exception throw by the sandbox for an security issue (Host A tried to call a function from Host B). (Thanks Adobe for the remote debugging !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that

```
 System.allowDomain
```

was not in the original example? It looks like the rest of the example is actionscript2 code, that would mean the allowDomain call is:

```
System.security.allowDomain
```

Comment: You are right, the allowDomain wasn't from the original code but I use everything I found that may solve the security issue like allowDomain().

I was sure both version of AS use the same namespace... (even after check the doc for AS2... ;() (I didn't read System.allowDomain() but Security.allowDomain(), that explain why I got a compiling error ^^')

Thanks !